# Rally Query in Custom App not returning expected results

Tags: rally

I am testing a rally query within the settings of a custom app and am unable to get the correct results returned.

I want to return defects with an open task that has specific text in the name only while any other tasks are complete and do not have the same specific text in the name.

The query I am using is:

(((((Tasks.Name !contains "someText") AND (Tasks.State = "Completed")) AND (Tasks.Name contains "someText")) AND (Tasks.State != "Completed"))

I have 1 test defect with 2 tasks for testing:
task 1 does not have the specific text and is complete and the other has the specified text and is not complete.
No information is returned.

If I split the query into separate parts and update the tasks to match
(((Tasks.Name !contains "someText") AND (Tasks.State = "Completed"))
The correct information is returned
as does
(((Tasks.Name contains "someText")) AND (Tasks.State != "Completed"))

How can I put both together?

I have searched the documentation for "nested" queries but I can't find anything applicable, perhaps this can't be done?  Can anyone help with the query syntax or help me understand where I am going wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Response from Rally that nested queries are not supported but they see great benefit in making this available.

Comment: (sorry, hit enter too early!)     Response from Rally that nested queries are not supported but they see great benefit in making this available.  I have therefore created a Rally Idea here: https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D3398 the more votes, the more likely Rally will look to implement!  Thanks everyone who vieved and if you think this is worth implementing, please vote at the link above!